# Llamalndex 0.9.30 stalls on VectorStoreIndex.from_documents()

Tags: llama-index

I am following the "Starter Tutorial" in the Llamalndex 0.9.30 official documentation. However, when I run the following code snippet on macOS, the program seems to stall at "index = VectorStoreIndex.from_documents(documents)" and nothing happens. Here is the code I am running:

```
from llama_index import VectorStoreIndex, SimpleDirectoryReader
documents = SimpleDirectoryReader("data").load_data()
index = VectorStoreIndex.from_documents(documents)
query_engine = index.as_query_engine()
response = query_engine.query("What did the author do growing up?")
print(response)
```

Additional information:
macOS version: 13.2.1 (22D68)
Chip: Apple M2 Pro

Does anyone know what might be causing this issue?